# porting C# addon for word from windows to mac

Tags: c#, windows, macos, ms-word

hello
I have an addon for word for windows written in C#. Is there any way to port this to the mac version without rewriting it in VBA ?

my addon works on word 2010 and 2007 (on windows)
the mac target should be word 2011

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to re-write in VBA since Office for Mac doesn't support .NET add-ins. There is something called Automator but it's much less capable than VBA.

Comment: and before you start your VBA port, check that the bits of the object model which are important to you are implemented.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445940/workarounds-for-gaps-in-word-for-mac-2011-vba-object-model