# Visual C# Office Addins for Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, macos, vsto, ms-office

I have a Office Addin which works well in MS Office 2007. Can I port this Addin to Mac? Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, the VSTO framework used to develop Office Add-ins is for Windows only :-(

Take a look at Microsofts system requirements for the VSTO framework: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20479

Comment: Worse, the VBA object model is incomplete as well.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445940/workarounds-for-gaps-in-word-for-mac-2011-vba-object-model