# VBA word form to excel: How/why are the dim's undefined?

Tags: excel, forms, macos, vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA (and learning code since 3 months:)) and cannot seem to get this code working. I'm trying to get form data (Word) to Excel and copied this code from a youtube video. For some reason, the dim's do not work (maybe because I'm working on a mac?).
New Word.Application (line 2), Word.Document (line 3), Word.ContentControl (line 4) give an error: User-Defined Type Not Defined.

Hopefully one of you can help me out:)

This is the code:

```
Sub getWordFormData()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim CCtl As Word.ContentControl
Dim myFolder As String, strFile As String
Dim myWkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long

myFolder = "/Users/me/Desktop/survey"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If myFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
Set myWkSht = Activesheet
Activesheet.Cells.Clear

Range("A1") = "Name"
Range("B1") = "Question 1"
Range("C1") = "Comments"
Range("D1") = "Question 2"
Range("E1") = "Comments"
Range("F1") = "Question 3"
Range("G1") = "Comments"

i = myWkSht.Cells(myWkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
strFile = Dir(myFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)

While strFile <> ""
i = i + 1

Set myDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(fileName:=myFolder & "\" & strFile,         AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)

With myDoc
j = 0
For Each CCtl In .contentControls
j = j + 1
myWkSht.Cells(i, j) = CCtl.Range.Text
Next
myWkSht.colums.AutoFit
End With
myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
strFile = Dir()
Wend
wdApp.Quit
Set myDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set myWkSht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this in excel? If so you need to add a reference to word??

Comment: Yes, true. However that does not seem to fix the error:(

Answer (score 0):

This code uses something called **Early Binding** which means a reference has been made to a library (in this case, Microsoft Word) - This has some advantages such as allowing the use of [intellsense](/questions/tagged/intellsense) within the VBE. To get the code working you have two options:

**1.** Convert the code to use **Late Binding** - for example:

```
Sub getWordFormData()
Dim wdApp As Object
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

---

**2.** Set a reference to the Microsoft Word Objects library:

- In the VBE go to Tools -> References.
- Find `Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library` and tick the checkbox on the left.
- Press OK, the go to Debug -> Compile

---

Some information on binding:

[Using early binding and late binding in automation - MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245115)
[VBA references and early binding Vs late binding - Excel Matters](http://excelmatters.com/2013/09/23/vba-references-and-early-binding-vs-late-binding/)

---

***NB:*** Just saw this comment:

> "maybe because I'm working on a mac?"

In which case you will have to use Early Binding, because ActiveX doesn't work on Mac - so Option 2 for you. But Content Controls don't work on Mac OS either so you will have to [use a workaround instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4503519/4240221)

Comment: Thanks! After compiling, the error for Dim CCtl As Word.ContentControl remains.

Comment: Did you add the reference?

Comment: I ticked the checkbox. Do I need to code a separate reference to word as well?

Comment: It could be because you're on a Mac. When I've got my laptop to hand I'll test it.

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot - just tested it on Windows and it was fine, however it doesn't work on Mac OS - after having a look around I discovered it's been covered before on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4503519/4240221 Basically content control doesn't work on Word for Mac

Comment: No problem. Too bad it doesn't work on Mac OS. Thanks for your help though:D